# How to justify items on flex-wrap?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a element with its children. I am applying flexbox on it for css. I used flex-wrap on it for wrapping the items to next line on overflow. But, when it wraps I want the top items to have space evenly and take the container whole width. Is it possible anyway? I am ok to use,grids or just CSS.

I want the elements from one to six to be spaced evenly on the top line and remaining items wrapped in the second line.

**Note: I don't want to apply justify-content: space-evenly as it spaces all the items and second line looks weird.**

```css
nav{
background: black;
max-width: 300px;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
a{
color: #0f0;
margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
<a>one</a>
<a>two</a>
<a>three</a>
<a>four five</a>
<a>six</a>
<a>seven eight</a>
<a>nine ten</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/rwfpm8g3/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`space-between,  space-evenly or space-around` in combination with pseudo element should do it

*More preferably **space-between***

```css
nav {
  background: black;
  max-width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
  justify-content: space-between;
}

a {
  color: #0f0;
  margin: 10px;
}

nav:after {
    content: '';
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a>one</a>
  <a>two</a>
  <a>three</a>
  <a>four five</a>
  <a>six</a>
  <a>seven eight</a>
  <a>nine ten</a>
</nav>
<p>Longer list </p>
<nav>
  <a>one</a>
  <a>two</a>
  <a>three</a>
  <a>four five</a>
  <a>six</a>
  <a>seven eight</a>
  <a>nine ten</a>
  <a>one</a>
  <a>two</a>
  <a>three</a>
  <a>four five</a>
  <a>six</a>
  <a>seven eight</a>
  <a>nine ten</a>
  <a>one</a>
  <a>two</a>
  <a>three</a>
  <a>four five</a>
  <a>six</a>
  <a>seven eight</a>
  <a>nine ten</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it meets all your needs, but I think you can do it like this

```css
nav {
  background: black;
  max-width: 300px;
  display:block;
  text-align: justify;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #0f0;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a>one</a>
  <a>two</a>
  <a>three</a>
  <a>four five</a>
  <a>six</a>
  <a>seven eight</a>
  <a>nine ten</a>
</nav>
```